# Аутентификация клиентов на сервере в соцсети

Tags: клиент-сервер, jwt, аутентификация, соцсети

При написании своей соцсети (по типу Telegram или VK) столкнулся с вопросом аутентификации клиентов на сервере. В интернете куча информации насчет различных способов аутентификации (через токены и пр.), поэтому вопрос: какой из них наиболее предпочтителен в данной задаче? Я, пока, решил остановиться на JWT токенах. Но тут же вопрос: насколько часто необходимо менять токены? какое время жизни им задавать? и пр. И нужны ли именно токены, или есть варианты получше?

Comment: Всё зависит от вашей задачи, ваших хотелок и ваших требований к производительности и безопасности. В зависимости от этого JWT может быть как идеальным выбором, так и абсолютно непригодным

Answer (score 0):

access токену можно дать 5-15мин жизни. refresh токену можно дать дней 10-15. Каких либо ограничений нет